# How to display for last 5 days audit record in the DB2 through an SQL statement day wise and show count of them day wise in a single row

Tags: sql, db2, audit

For the admin I performing certain type of sql operation. Records are of the following type.

```
date        number of failed login
13/02/2017            1
12/02/2017            2
11/02/2017            0
10/02/2017            9
09/02/2017            0
```

I want the 0,9,0,2,1 in a single row.

I have tried the below query. But failed to get the zero by default.
On which user day the user has performed zero operation has to be there.

```
select LISTAGG(cnt, ', ') 
from (select count(*) as cnt 
      from OPERATIONINFO 
      where OPERATIONTYPE='FAILEDLOGIN' 
        and CUSTID = 123 
        and date(UPDATEDDATEOFLOGIN) > (current date - 5 day)  
      group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
```

Please help.

Comment: I formatted your code so that it is readable and it is clear you are missing a `)` -- where does it go?  Before the group by?

Comment: thanks..near group by i missed the bracket..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data using decode.  have a look at this example which takes this

```
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES
(2004, 1, 20),
(2004, 2, 30),
(2004, 3, 15),
(2004, 4, 10),
(2005, 1, 18),
(2005, 2, 40),
(2005, 3, 12),
(2005, 4, 27);
```

to this

```
Year Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
---- -- -- -- --
2004 20 30 15 10
2005 18 40 12 27
```

[by using decode in db2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en)

```
SELECT Year,
       MAX(DECODE(Quarter, 1, Results)) AS Q1,
       MAX(DECODE(Quarter, 2, Results)) AS Q2,            
       MAX(DECODE(Quarter, 3, Results)) AS Q3,
       MAX(DECODE(Quarter, 4, Results)) AS Q4
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY Year;
```

Comment: I want zero by default. This only fetches the record if the user has performed any operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dates table... here I make on on the fly using recursion -- not the best way...

```
WITH DATES_TABLE AS 
(
   SELECT CURRENT DATE - 5 DAYS AS D FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT D + 1 DAY AS D FROM DATES_TABLE WHERE D < CURRENT DATE
), THE_DATA AS
(
  select D.D, SUM(CASE WHEN O.UPDATEDDATEOFLOGIN IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt 
  from DATES_TABLE D
  LEFT JOIN OPERATIONINFO O ON O.UPDATEDDATEOFLOGIN = D.D
  where O.OPERATIONTYPE='FAILEDLOGIN' 
    and O.CUSTID = 123 
  group by D.D

)
select  LISTAGG(cnt, ', ') 
from THE_DATA
```